# Can't start MySQL due to an error in a View

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

Good day,

I tried to upgrade mysql today (Ubuntu updates), but it failed. I checked `/var/log/mysql/error.log` and it says

> Error in parsing View 'database'.'view_name' during upgrade. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc' at line 1

I guess I need to remove the View, but I can't since I can't start the mysql server. Is there a way to fix this issue, like deleting the files of the View?

Comment: See if [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/196795/cannot-start-mysql) helps.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You might let Ubuntu repair all packages -- it will try to keep them consistent.

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to open *Terminal.
- Enter `sudo apt update --fix-missing`, press  <kbd>Enter</kbd> and enter your password (no prompt is shown). This completes updating, if interrupted.
- When that finishes, enter `sudo apt install -f` and press  <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then  <kbd>y</kbd>. This is the first step in fixing broken packages.
- Then enter `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to fix more packages.

This likely will fix the issue. If not, see [PhoenixNAP](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ubuntu-fix-broken-packages) for more fixes.

Finally, check that all packages are OK in the [Synaptic Package Manager](https://itsfoss.com/synaptic-package-manager/).

Comment: It doesn't seem it's because of broken packages, but rather because of deprecated ASC and DESC with GROUP BY and the View uses DESC. I tried installing Percona 5.5, but now mysql doesn't start and there is nothing in the log.
Well I also ran the commands you wrote, but with already uninstalled mysql 8 and installed 5.5.

Comment: So I removed everything and installed Percona 5.5 again. It works, for now.